# Why MySQL BIT_OR() is returning different value than PHP bitwise operation

Tags: php, mysql, bit-manipulation, aggregate-functions, bitwise-operators

I have the following data in a MySQL table

"Data Dump"
    2   phone_calls 001
    2   phone_calls 010
    2   phone_calls 100
    2   phone_calls 1000
    2   phone_calls 10000
    2   phone_calls 100000

if I run PHP code to do bitwise Or operation like so

```
echo bindec('001') | bindec('010') | bindec('100') | bindec('1000') | bindec('10000') | bindec('100000');
```

I get 63 for output "which is expected"

if I do the Or manually

```
000001
000010
000100
001000
010000
100000
======
111111

the result = 111111 which is `32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 63`
```

When I run the following query in MySQL

```
SELECT user_id, section_name, BIT_OR(permission_type) AS final
FROM permissions
WHERE section_name ='phone_calls' and user_id = 2
GROUP BY user_id, section_name
```

which is basically running [BIT_OR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) on "Data Dump" listed above and the output is

```
 2  phone_calls 108543
```

why MySQL gives me 108543 and PHP gives me 63? How can I get MySQL to give me 63?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`108543` is what you get when you `or` together the *decimal* values `{1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000}`.

In other words, they're not being treated as binary values.

You either need to store the correct decimal values for the binary equivalents, `{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32}`, or find a way to convert decimal variants holding only `0` and `1` digits into an appropriate value.

If you want to retain strings holding the bit pattern, they can be converted into decimal with something like:

```
conv(colname,2,10)
```

which does a [base conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv):

```
mysql> select conv('10',2,10);
    -> '2'
mysql> select conv('1000',2,10);
    -> '8'
```

Comment: I got it :) I will give you the correct answer. but I left an answer for the next person below :) Thank you so much. What should I make the column type to avid conversion?

Comment: @Mike, you can leave it as is since the solution works. I myself would probably have stored an integral type rather than a string since the operations would tend to be faster, at least with regular databases. Whether that's the case for MySQL, I don't know. If it, as I seem to remember, stores everything as strings any way, the difference might not be so much. In any case, the first commandment of optimisation is "measure, don't guess" and the second is "check your authorities, don't trust some random bod of the internet just because they sound knowledgeable" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got it :)

```
SELECT user_id, section_name, BIT_OR(CONV(permission_type, 2, 10)) AS final
FROM data_import.permissions
WHERE section_name ='phone_calls' and user_id = 2
GROUP BY user_id, section_name
```